# In OCaml, I defined in AST file that stmt can be stmt or stmt List, but when used in function, it reports error

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I defined in AST file that stmt=|stmt|stmt List. Then I have a function with parameter of type stmt, I cannot use stmt List? Can anyone tell me how to make it work?

The error when compiling is:

```
Error: This expression has type Ast.stmt list
       but an expression was expected of type Ast.stmt
```

Below is my code for function:

```
let rec eval_stmt (stmt:stmt) (ps:proc_state) (env:environment) (store:store) : (stmtEvalRes*proc_state*store) = match stmt with
| PrintInt e ->
    let r = eval_expr e ps env store in
    print_int r; (Next, ps, store)
| PrintStr s ->
    print_string (Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "\\\\n") "\n" s); 
    (* Escaping characters here because it's not done in the parser *)
    (Next, ps, store)
| List (stmt1::stmts) -> eval_stmt stmt1 ps env store;
    eval_stmt stmts ps env store;(Next,ps,store)
```

Below is my AST file:

```
type stmt = (* Statements in C-flat language *)
  Empty 
| VarAss of expr * expr

(* Expressions can be statements in themselves. This is most useful when
   the expression is a function call. Calls to built-in functions are
   just special cases of calls. *)
| Expr of expr 
| PrintStr of string (* string is only static! *)
| PrintInt of expr (* expr should be int *)

(* Control Flow *)
| IfThen of cond * stmt
| IfThenElse of cond * stmt * stmt
| Switch of expr * (int * stmt list) list * stmt list 
  (* Switch (cond, cases, default) *)

| While of cond * stmt
| For of stmt * cond * stmt * stmt

| Break (* used in switch, while and for *)
| Continue (* used in while and for *)

(* nested statements *)
| List of stmt list 
;;
```

Comment: You might want to format your code a little better; it's very hard to read right now. It should be enough just to indent it all by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your define `stmt` as a variant type, i.e., a finite collection of alternatives. One of the alternatives is `List` which indeed contains a `stmt list`. But this doesn't mean that `stmt list` is the same type as `stmt`. What it means is that a value `List ...` (with a list of statements inside) is of type `stmt`.